# Can a disagreement button and comment be allowed in audit tests?

Tags: feature-request, comments, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

The audit process seems very one-way....I'm not sure who decides whether one question/comment is good or bad or even the selection of question/answers for audit but I think that I am not alone in thinking that some of these calls are different than I might make and have some good rationale.

There is no way to make comments on the specific selections that would cycle back to the deciders/selectors so that the audit selection/review criteria could be improved.

I suggest that reviews be allowed to comment on the deciders' selection.  Maybe implementation of a button allowing a person to comment on the solution.

Comment: You may be right...anything being done to get something implemented?

Comment: There's been a lot of crossed fingers, some prayer, and one seance. Also a few bounties.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically, so if you disagree, visit the post itself, and give it the opposite action (downvote an upvoted post, or vice versa). This will remove it from consideration for future audits. But a handful of failed audits isn't a big deal, as long as it's not a pattern.

Comment: Audits are choosen randomly using active questions/answers?  How are the "right" responses chosen?

Comment: @mdpc They're not chosen among all questions.  Audits representing "bad stuff" is chosen from among content that has been flagged and deleted by mods.  Audits representing "good stuff" are chosen from posts that meet criteria including more than X upvotes, no downvotes, no close votes, no flags, and possibly a few more.  (X is set at 5, currently.)  If one of these "good" posts is in fact a bad post, you only need to downvote/closevote/flag to disqualify it as a future audit.

Comment: OK...that is how the questions are chosen.  What about the "right" responses?  Based on the pool where the question/answer was pulled from?